# H2 MUCH SLOWER than HSQLDB in my Java application? (both inmem)

Tags: h2, hsqldb

I am sure there's something stupid from my side going on here.

I have a Java application where I need to query a collection of 2,5 Million objects repeatedly all the time, therefore I put them into an in memory db.

For this purpose I tried out
hsqldb
v2.4.1
and 
h2
v1.4.198

For both I use exactly the same create table:

```
String createRateTable = "CREATE MEMORY TABLE INTEREST_RATES " +
                                "(EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE not NULL, "
                                + "INTEREST_RATE DOUBLE, "
                                + "INTEREST_RATE_CD BIGINT, "
                                + "INTEREST_RATE_TERM BIGINT, "
                                + "INTEREST_RATE_TERM_MULT VARCHAR(50),"
                                + "PRIMARY KEY (EFFECTIVE_DATE, INTEREST_RATE_CD, INTEREST_RATE_TERM, INTEREST_RATE_TERM_MULT))";
```

The only difference is the Connection, either I take

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:ftp", "SA", "");
```

or

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsql:mem:ftp", "SA", "");
```

An often fired query for example is this one:

```
SELECT * 
from INTEREST_RATES 
where INTEREST_RATE_CD = ? 
  and EFFECTIVE_DATE = (SELECT MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) 
                        from INTEREST_RATES 
                        where INTEREST_RATE_CD = ?)
```

Now...

as for Hsql the application is finished within about 2 minutes.

as for H2 it's still not done after > 8 minutes.

What's wrong with my H2 setup? Seems like there are no indices created there, as Hsql does with help of the PRIMARY KEY ()? What else can be the problem?

Comment: Similar performance results can be seen here: http://www.jpab.org/Hibernate/H2/server/Hibernate/HSQLDB/embedded.html maybe there is nothing wrong from your side and hsqldb is just faster?

Comment: Yeah but this is like a day and night difference, something that makes me really think I didn't set up H2 correctly...

Comment: HSQLDB optimises both the main query and the subquery. Try EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * from INTEREST_RATES ... to see how it uses the primary key index. Query optimisations are not often reflected in many so-called "performace tests", which use very simple queries.

Comment: @Kuikiker Comparing H2 embedded/HSQLDB embedded shows less performance difference https://www.jpab.org/Hibernate/H2/embedded/Hibernate/HSQLDB/embedded.html

Answer (score 0):

Each DB engine has it's own implementation and in some scenarios can behave different.
I would try the following query, I think the index could be more efficiently used and returns the same result:

```
SELECT * 
from INTEREST_RATES 
where INTEREST_RATE_CD = ?
order by INTEREST_RATE_CD, EFFECTIVE_DATE
limit 1;
```

In the "order by" the first column is not really required as is already filtered but as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091367/h2-database-slow-query-although-index-is-used) is needed so the PRIMARY KEY is correctly used by the engine in the execution plan.